# Mathematical model of the compression of a syringe by means of the action of a motor

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations, flow, software

Does anyone know how I can get a hydrodynamic model of the compression of a syringe by means of the force of a motor ($ F_ {M} $). Where $ F_ {atm} $ is the force due to atmospheric pressure, $ F_ {r} $ is the frictional force obtained by the friction between the plunger and the walls of the syringe and $ F_ {l} $ is the force opposition of the fluid? In the end, what I want to obtain is an equation that relates the output flow to the input pressure exerted by the motor.

[image]

I made a mathematical model where I obtained this equation:

$Q=\sqrt((\frac{2}{(ρ(\frac{A_1}{A_3} - 1)})*(\frac{P_int}{A_1} - A_1 ρg(h_3-h_1 )-F_{r}))$

But the output I got does not fit my simulation in COMSOL software that I did with the following parameters:

[image]

These were the data obtained in COMSOL:

[image]

This was the graph in COMSOL before an inlet pressure of $ 0.010561 N⁄m ^ 2 $, here I obtained a maximum speed of 0.000020m / s, therefore, a flow of $ 1.255537 * 10 ^ {- 10} m ^ 3 / s $ flow rate

[image]